# How exactly is calculated hypothetical main size of flex item - CSS Spec question

Tags: css, flexbox, specifications

I have flex container with fixed width of 600px. Its flex item has `flex-basis: 0` with 1px border and 16px padding. Based on spec flex base size of such item should be 0 (based on info in spec https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-main-item, first paragraph after E section). What is hypothetical main sizes of such item? 34 pixels (border + padding), 0px or -34px? I'm not entirely sure about this from reading the spec.

Now when calculating flex item size based on [Spec section 9.7 Resolving flexible lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths). Flex factor will be `flex-grow`. Here based on my experiments I'm guessing hypothetical main size is actually 34px (not 0 or -34px) and thus the item is not freezed. But the initial free space will not be 600px (since flex-base size is 0), but only 566px (We extracted hypothetical main size from container size, 600px - 34px = 566px).

Is that correct assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes correct. In the Specification you can read:

> The hypothetical main size is the item’s flex base size **clamped according to its used min and max main sizes** (and flooring the content box size at zero).

So your min size here is `34px` (padding and border) and the item will not be freezed like you noticed. It will be in case you are using `flex-shrink:1` (which is the default value) and `flex-grow:0`

```css
.box {
  border:1px solid;
  display:flex;
  width:600px;
}
.box div {
  padding:16px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:blue;
  flex-shrink:1;
  flex-basis:0;
}

.box span {
  width:100%;
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-basis:100%;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div></div> <span></span>
</div>
```

As you can see the element will not shrink because it's freezed.

> if using the flex shrink factor: any item that has a flex base size smaller than its hypothetical main size